# Add both !important & selector strategy for tailwind configuration

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[image]

I have got the CMS application with bootstrap, and embedding react application with tailwind css into it.
There are clashes with both css framework util classes.

I enabled `!important` via tailwind configuration then have the below issue, Also tried with selector strategy via config as important: `.tailwind-app`, but still bootstrap !important rules override. I need to increase the specificity and add add !important to tailwind classes so that application will work without affected.

I don't want to use pre-fixing styles for tailwind because, there are some components loaded from my component library, in which I don't want to make changes
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5080

Comment: I  hope this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I guess the above is the best way to show what is happening with css overriding, above is not code, I would have copied it if that is code

Comment: @Nouphal.M Yes, You are right with specificity but the issue is with tailwind configuration where I cannot add both specificity & !important

Comment: @jithureddy, please mark the answer that helped you, as right ;-)

Answer (score 167):

**Built-in important modifier**

You can make any utility important by adding a ! character to the beginning:

```html
<button class="!bg-green-500">Hello</button>
```

Output

```css
.\!bg-green-500 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1 !important;
    background-color: rgb(34 197 94 / var(--tw-bg-opacity)) !important
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier

Comment: You are right, but want to add both css selectors & !important using built in modifier.

Comment: I'm having issues with this compiling in laravel mix. I keep getting `SassError: expected ";".234 │  @apply !mr-[6px];`

Comment: I am, as well.  I can't figure how to get it to compile with the important modifier anywhere.

Answer (score 30):

In order to make the SASS compiler happy you need to use this syntaxe :

```
@apply bg-transparent w-auto #{!important};
```

It put all the "**@apply**" line in "*!important*" on the output.

See there : https://github.com/tailwindlabs/discuss/issues/224

Comment: this is deprecated

Comment: also tailwind itself said @apply is "premature abstraction"
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles

Answer (score 26):

To use `!important` and a modifier like `:hover` then instead of:

`!hover:underline`

You'd want:

`hover:!underline`

Answer (score 8):

**In tailwindcss**

class="!flex"

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary screen size values, when you need to hide or show something:

min-[950px]:!block

Answer (score 0):

For me following code is working:

> @apply text-white !important;

This produces:

```
.side-menu--itemactive a {
--tw-text-opacity: 1 !important;
color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity)) !important;}
```

This solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

in Sass with Tailwind this is working fine

```
 @apply flex justify-between pt-0 #{!important};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered a handy technique in Sass when working with Tailwind CSS. This approach helps enhance specificity without resorting to the use of `!important`.

In situations where you want to target a specific class within Tailwind without sacrificing specificity, you can leverage the & symbol in Sass. Here's a quick example:

```
.anotherClass {
  color: blue;

  &[class*='certainClass'] {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

In the above snippet, the `[class*='certainClass']` selector is appended to `.anotherClass`, providing a more specific rule for elements that have both classes. This can be particularly useful when you need to apply additional styling without resorting to !important.
In the context of Tailwind CSS, a similar specificity boost can be achieved by prefixing a class with `[&]` For example: `[&]:font-light`

[image]

Adding `[&]` before a Tailwind class, as demonstrated above, enhances its specificity, offering a clean and effective solution without relying on `!important`.